# What is the purpose of returning a char* in strcat, strcopy, (etc), when there is a destination variable?

Tags: c, string

Just a silly but quick question:  Why do some functions that work with c style strings such as: fgets, strcpy, strcat, etc, have a return type of char* when there is a variable in the parameter list that stores the output? ie, why is it:

```
char *strcat ( char *dest, const char *src );
```

and not

```
void strcat ( char *dest, const char *src );
```

or even just returning the result by doing

```
char *strcat (const char *src );
```

I mean I can see how this would be useful if you are nesting calls to these functions (which is dangerous) but I don't see why you need to have both a destination variable AND returnt he result...

I'm reviewing some c programming stuff and can't believe how much I forgot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of ease of usage, so that these functions can be used in larger expressions or can be nested.

Something like:

```
strcat(path, strcpy(file, "foo.txt"));
```

or

```
printf("[%s]\n", strcat(string1, string2));
```

Needless to say these usages can and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

In certain cases, by checking the return value for NULL also gives an indication of whether the function succeeded or not. Not necessarily ideal practise however.